# How can I get the Intent extras for a PendingIntent that is already pending?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have scheduled a `PendingIntent` with `AlarmManager`.  When the `AlarmManager` delivers the `Intent`, I am able to `getExtras()` all the data that I originally sent.

However, sometimes I get additional data that I want to pass with the `Intent`, before the `AlarmManager` fires.  My thought was, I would just get the `Intent` like I was going to cancel it, but then after cancelling it, update the extras and reschedule it with the `AlarmManager`, like this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id,i, 0);
if (b == null) b = i.getExtras(); // in case I can't get it before calling getBroadcast
// now add a key to b, put it in a new intent, schedule it, and cancel the old one?
```

I'm calling `getBroadcast()` with the same id as I schedule it with earlier.  The only problem is, when I call `getExtras()` it always returns null.  This seems to be kind of the reverse of the problem I have seen frequently where an `Intent` will be cached and that is not desired.  In this case I actually want to get the cached `Intent` and get the value for it, and since the `Intent` is pending it should still be there.

How do I do this?

A couple of ideas I have had and/or tried.  One revolves around the `Intent.fillIn()` function, could I perhaps use this to indicate that it should (or should not) overwrite the extras so that I can retrieve the original ones.

Looking a bit further, I see that `PendingIntent` has `writeToParcel()`.  Can I use this to get access to the extras of the attached `Intent`? My attempt failed with `readBundle: bad magic number` exception on readParcel:

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id,i, 0);
Parcel out = Parcel.obtain();
pi.writeToParcel(out, 0);
i.readFromParcel(out);
```

I suspect that maybe this is because I am outputting a `PendingIntent` but trying to read it back as an `Intent`.

The other idea is that I could call send() on the `PendingIntent` to cause it to be immediately delivered, passing a new `Intent` with a new key to add.  Then in the handler I would have to iterate through all keys in the extras of the intent. It would then need to re-issue the `PendingIntent` to the `AlarmManager` if it wasn't time yet to do the actual processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution to this problem.

It doesn't seem to be possible to get the `Intent` from a `PendingIntent`, but it is possible to add extras in the `Intent` passed to `getBroadcast()` - it is important that the last parameter, the flags, be zero so that it won't overwrite the existing extras.

Also, the extras contain name/value pairs, and it is important that the new key added not match a key in the existing `Intent`.  This means that `removeExtra()` must be called when done to get rid of the key before next time. Then call `send()` on the `PendingIntent` targeting oneself, and then when receiving the intent it is possible to access both the new and old extras.  Both extras can then be collected into a new `Intent` and then the `AlarmManager` can be called to reschedule.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, i, 
                       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Here we are sending the **PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** intent flag, if same PendingIntent exists it will be return as is, otherwise a new PendingIntent will be returned.

Please note when we say intent match, URI,Data type, Category will be matched, while intent extras will be ignored while matching. In other words **IntentFilters** will be matched of both intents.

Comment: No luck.  The extras in the intent are still null.  I suspect, from reading the documentation, that what is happening is that the PendingIntent functions aren't returning any data in the passed Intent, they are only taking it.